# docx.js Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11509:70)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs

I have an issue. When I import a library and use any component I get an error. How can I fix that? I have no clues or guesses,

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11509:70)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Example usage. But result is always the same.

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import * as docx from 'docx';

// const { Document } = docx;

export const downloadDocx = () => {
  // @ts-ignore
  const document = new docx.Document({
    sections: [{
      children: [
        new docx.Paragraph({
          children: [new docx.TextRun('Hello World')],
        }),
      ],
    }],
  });

  docx.Packer.toBlob(document).then((blob) => {
    saveAs(blob, 'document.docx');
  });
};
```

I use react and a typescript. What I have for a tsconfig.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

What bothers me is that it refers to the ambiguity. 11509:70. There is no 70 chars at this line.
[image]

**Maybe that's a babel preset issue? Well. Still no clue which presets I should've install.**